# Using std::unique_ptr<…> to manage CoreFoundation CFType resources

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, core-foundation, cftypes

I am using a `std::unique_ptr` to manage opaque types from the CoreFoundation framework. CoreFoundation types (aka `CFTypes`) must be manually released, so my recipe for the `std::unique_ptr` type looks like this:

```c
namespace detail {

    template <typename CoreFoundationType>
    struct cfreleaser {
        constexpr cfreleaser() noexcept = default;
        template <typename U> cfreleaser(cfreleaser<U> const&) noexcept {};
        void operator()(CoreFoundationType __attribute__((cf_consumed)) cfp) {
            if (cfp) { CFRelease(cfp); cfp = nullptr; }
        }
    };

    template <typename CoreFoundationType>
    using cfp_t = std::unique_ptr<
                  typename std::decay_t<
                           std::remove_pointer_t<CoreFoundationType>>,
                                      cfreleaser<CoreFoundationType>>;
}
```

… this arrangement lets me go from manually releasing `CFType` resources, e.g.:

```c
CGColorSpaceRef deviceRGB = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
/// … make use of `deviceRGB`
CGColorSpaceRelease(deviceRGB); /// release `deviceRGB`
```

… to an automatic-release scheme, like so:

```c
detail::cfp_t<CGColorSpaceRef> deviceRGB(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB());
/// … make use of `deviceRGB`
/// … `deviceRGB` releases automatically on scope exit
```

… this means that I end up releasing every one of the `CFType` instances I create with `CFRelease(…)` – never using whatever specialized release function may exist for that `CFType` (`CGColorSpaceRelease(…)` in the above example snippet).

In my perusal of [the CoreFoundation docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics?language=objc) – as well as the docs for `CFType`-based frameworks [like CoreGraphics](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics?language=objc) – every custom releaser function I have seen has been written up as “the equivalent of `CFRelease`” ([for example](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1586509-cgcontextrelease?language=objc)) … my question is, are there any exceptions to this generality? In other words, is it safe to use `CFRelease(…)` on any and all `CFType` instances, as I am doing in this case with `std::unique_ptr`?